# Android Webview: Override Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar, overriding, contextual-action-bar

I am trying to override a contextual action bar in Android Webview. When I long click on a selected word, the custom action bar is displayed. However, when I click on the action bar button, nothing happens.

It seems like the `onContextItemSelected()` function is not called. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dictionary);
   mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save_word:
            Toast.makeText(CheckDictionary.this,"Save Word Meaning Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (mActionMode != null) {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        mode.setTitle("Save Word Meaning");
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        menu.clear();
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dictionary_menu, menu);
    }
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}

@Override
public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
    mActionMode = null;
    super.onActionModeFinished(mode);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing this job on my old projects like this:

```
 private String[] data = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10"};

 private SelectionAdapter mAdapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mAdapter = new SelectionAdapter(this,
                 R.layout.row_list_item, R.id.textView1, data);
     setListAdapter(mAdapter);
     getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

     getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

         private int nr = 0;

         @Override
         public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              mAdapter.clearSelection();
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             nr = 0;
             MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
             inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
             return true;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             switch (item.getItemId()) {

                 case R.id.item_delete:
                     nr = 0;
                     mAdapter.clearSelection();
                     mode.finish();
             }
            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                 long id, boolean checked) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if (checked) {
                     nr++;
                     mAdapter.setNewSelection(position, checked);                    
                 } else {
                     nr--;
                     mAdapter.removeSelection(position);                 
                 }
                 mode.setTitle(nr + " selected");

         }
     });

     getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

         @Override
         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<? arg0, View arg1,
                 int position, long arg3) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             getListView().setItemChecked(position, !mAdapter.isPositionChecked(position));
             return false;
         }
     });
 }

 private class SelectionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String {

     private HashMap<Integer, Boolean mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean();

     public SelectionAdapter(Context context, int resource,
             int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
         super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
     }

     public void setNewSelection(int position, boolean value) {
         mSelection.put(position, value);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     public boolean isPositionChecked(int position) {
         Boolean result = mSelection.get(position);
         return result == null ? false : result;
     }

     public Set<Integer getCurrentCheckedPosition() {
         return mSelection.keySet();
     }

     public void removeSelection(int position) {
         mSelection.remove(position);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     public void clearSelection() {
         mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean();
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);//let the adapter handle setting up the row views
         v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));


         if (mSelection.get(position) != null) {
             v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);

         }
         return v;
     }
 }
```

You can make changes in this code according to your needs...

Answer (score 0):

try below steps

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {
    MyActivity theListener;
    Context context;
    GestureDetector gd;

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        this.context = context;
        gd = new GestureDetector(context, sogl);
    }

    // This is new
    public void setListener(MyActivity l) {
        theListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener sogl =
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
            theListener.onLongClick(MyWebView.this);
        }
    };
}
```

and in activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    MyWebView mwv = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.mwv);
    registerForContextMenu(mwv);
}

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    openContextMenu(v);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not so understand the purpose of MyWebView class. Where I person the action of onContextItemSelected? like perform action when I click on button R.id.save_word?

Comment: we need to overwrite longclick of web view that whats why i am custumized the web view in your activity just overwrite @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save_word:
            Toast.makeText(CheckDictionary.this,"Save Word Meaning Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (mActionMode != null) {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

Comment: But doesn''t work for me. The error comes on   registerForContextMenu(mwv);

Comment: go through this link http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View) and let me cross check why it come thanks

Comment: But I still cannot understand MyWebView mwv = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.mwv); For R.id.mwv, it is id for webview in layout. It may have syntax error. It object for webview id. If it declare by MyWebView object, it may have syntax error. Thanks for more explanation.